# Vite react.js application showing 404 not found in nginx server after right config

Tags: reactjs, nginx, deployment, react-router, vite

I uploaded Vite react.js application to a server. I'm using nginx server. Application is working fine. But when I go to another page & refresh, the site is not working. It's showing a 404 Not found error. I've added the following configuration in the nginx still the problem persists

```
 location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

The application is configured as a subdirectory like **[www.domain.com/stock/app](http://www.domain.com/stock/app)** when I refresh upto the given url it is working fine but when I switch to other routes like **[www.domain.com/stock/app/login](http://www.domain.com/stock/app/login)** or **[www.domain.com/stock/app/dashboard](http://www.domain.com/stock/app/dashboard)** and refresh the page it shows **404 Not Found**.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Yes, I've fixed this. There was some problem with nginx configuration. After fixing the config it started working!

Comment: @Arunprasath how did you solve the issue? could you kindly share the answer in the question?